# Angular - Filtering Global Data Service for Multiple Component Instances

Tags: angular, filter, service, observable

I have a sample Angular app with a global data service that I am trying to share between multiple instances of a component by filtering it.  This is a prototype for my bigger application, but I'm having the same issue in both.  I have tried to use a pipe filter, but I get an error message.  For now, I'd like some guidance on best practice in this situation as this is my first time trying to do this.  If it is pipe filtering, then I'd like help on the error message.

My example uses a test API that returns ToDo items.  I want to use the service for a component that shows completed items in one instance and incomplete items in another.  There is also filtering by userId just because I felt I needed another element to this.

Service:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

    export interface Todo {
      userId: number;
      id: number;
      title: string;
      completed: boolean;
    }

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class TodosService {
      private _todos$: BehaviorSubject<Todo[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      // Public Methods
      get todos() {
        return this._todos$.asObservable();
      }

      loadData() {
        this._listTodos()
          .subscribe(
            res => {
              this._todos$.next(res);
            },
            err => console.log('Error receiving todo items.', err)
          );
      }
      addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        this._addTodo(todo).subscribe( item => {
          const d = this._todos$.getValue();
          d.push(item);
          this._todos$.next(d);
        });
      }

      // Private methods
      _listTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
        return this.http.get<Todo[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
      }
      _addTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
        return this.http.post<Todo>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', todo);
      }
    }
```

Component:

```
    <div>
        <button (click)="addTodo()">Add Todo</button>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="(todosService.todos | todoFilter$: complete: userId | async) as todos">
        <h1>Completed: {{ complete }} UserId: {{ userId }} </h1>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">
                {{ todo.id}} - {{ todo.userId }} - {{ todo.title }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ng-container>
```

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
    import { Todo, TodosService} from '../../services/todos.service';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-todo',
      templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
    })
    export class TodoComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input() complete: false;
      @Input() userId: number = null;

      constructor(private todosService: TodosService) { }

      ngOnChanges() {
        this.load();
      }

      async load() {
        await this.todosService.loadData();
      }

      addTodo() {
        const t: Todo = {
          id: 999,
          userId: this.userId,
          title: 'Css Add',
          completed: this.complete
        };
        this.todosService.addTodo(t);
      }

    }
```

Pipe Filter (throws error:  Cannot read property 'filter' of null.  kws is null apparently but I'm not sure why if items$ is populated?):

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { Todo } from '../services/todos.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'todoFilter$'
    })
    export class TodoFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(items$: Observable<Todo[]>, complete: boolean, userId: number): any {
        if (!items$ || items$ == null || items$ === undefined) { return null; }

        return items$.pipe(map(
          kws => kws.filter(kw => (kw.completed === complete && (!userId || kw.userId === userId))
          ))
        );
      }
    }
```

App Component Sample Page:

```
<app-todo complete="false"></app-todo>
<app-todo complete="true" userId="1"></app-todo>
```

Please tell me what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you get the error because the initial value of the todo stream is null:

```
 private _todos$: BehaviorSubject<Todo[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

The early return in your pipe:

```
 if (!items$ || items$ == null || items$ === undefined) { return null; }
```

Will not ignore the null, since the observable `items$` is not null, but the first value emitted by it is (`kws`).

I would change so that instead of null, the initial value of the todos are an empty array. That would also simplify the template (no need for the ngIf, it would always have a value.)

In terms of the design I'm not sure, hopefully someone else can give you a better answer, here are a few thoughts:

1. The `app-todo` component, is it really not two different components? Perhaps the inner list of todos is the shared part. Depends on your goal of course.
2. Remove the pipe and keep the filtering in the service: Instead of just having the `todo` method, add `notCompleted` and `completed` methods (or something) that return the filtered todos.
3. I like to think in "smart" and "dumb" components (just google for a bunch of articles on it). In this context I think it basically means that perhaps the `app-todo` component would, instead of knowing about the pipes, show completed todos or not, the todo service, etc. would just receive an array of Todos as its input (already passed through the `async` pipe in the parent component). If a new todo is added, it could be an output on the component.

Comment: Ok, I tried initiating it to a blank array and now there is no error but I was getting no data back.  After messing with it some more, I had to convert all comparisons in the filter() to strings??  I'm not sure why that is?  This is what I ended up with:

kws => kws.filter(kw => (kw.completed.toString() === complete.toString()
        && (!userId || kw.userId.toString() === userId.toString()))

Comment: Ah, I think it's because the `@Input() complete: false;`, is when bound like this `complete="false"` is actually a string and not the boolean value. You could convert it to a boolean value in your component or change the binding to `[complete]="false"` (which then means that the value of `complete` javascript, not text)

If you still have issues I suggest re-creating your prototype in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular, that way it's easier for anyone else to test, edit and come with more suggestions.